# How to write 'map only' hadoop jobs?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm a novice on hadoop, I'm getting familiar to the style of map-reduce programing but now I faced a problem : Sometimes I need only map for a job and I only need the map result directly as output, which means reduce phase is not needed here, how can I achive that?

Comment: Check this [Map-only Jobs](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/05/map-only-jobs-in-hadoop.html)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This turns off the reducer.

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setNumReduceTasks(int)

Comment: Thank you Thomas, there still remains a problem: after set number of reduce tasks to 0, how to save the map result on hdfs? (I mean how to write map results to files like part-m-*****)

Comment: Hadoop does this for you, you don't need to care about it.

Comment: Do we need to specify reduce output key and value in this case ?

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the IdentityReducer:

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityReducer.html

Comment: Thank you Peter, I read the source of IdentityReducer, it's really what I meant to do, but are there any method to directly output the map result to HDFS without reduce? (you know the shuffle phase costs lots of bandwidth and cpu/memory resource)

Comment: IdentityMapper can be used with or without a follow-on reducer.  If you use the identity mapper to jump straight thru to the reduce stage you still have the sort-and-shuffle and i/o overhead so using the method mentioned by Thomas is the right way to go if you don't need a reducer.

Comment: I'm sorry omnisis, but that's not correct: Setting the number of reduce tasks to zero will omit any sorting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630447/hadoop-difference-between-0-reducer-and-identity-reducer

Answer (score 5):

Can be quite helpful when you need to launch job with mappers only from terminal. You can turn off reducers by specifing 0 reducers in hadoop jar command implicitly:

```
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=0
```

So the result command will be following:

```
hadoop jar myJob.jar -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 -input myInputDirs -output myOutputDir
```

To be backward compatible, Hadoop also supports the "-reduce NONE" option, which is equivalent to "-D mapred.reduce.tasks=0".

Comment: Now hadoop gives a depreciation warning for -D mapred.reduce.tasks and recommends to use -D mapreduce.job.reduce instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oozie as a scheduler to manager your hadoop jobs, then you can just set the property mapred.reduce.tasks(which is the default number of reduce tasks per job) to 0. You can add your mapper in the property mapreduce.map.class, and also there will be no need to add the property mapreduce.reduce.class since reducers are not required.

```
<configuration>
   <property>
     <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
     <value>my.com.package.AbcMapper</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
     <value>0</value>
   </property>
   .
   .
   .
<configuration>
```